# Unable to set SelectedValue in Combobox using DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, datatrigger

I have a comboBox that has a datatrigger that set its SelectedIndex based on a .NET Property's value that in the VM.  My problem is that I can't get the setter to set the Selected Index.

The ItemSource is based on a enum array.
The DataContext of the Window is the VM which has the Modulation, and Bandwidth properties.

I'm new to WPF so I'm sure I'm not understanding binding correctly, but I'm pulling my hair out!  Thanks for your help in advance.

Here's the Style.

```
    <Style x:Key="BWCombBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                        Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <DataTrigger 
                Binding="{Binding Modulation}" Value="P25">
                <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="2"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Here's the ComboBox:

```
   <ComboBox Name="bandwidth" 
             Height="Auto" Width="70"
             Style="{StaticResource BWCombBoxStyle}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding BandwidthOptions, Mode=OneWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             SelectedValue="{Binding IFBandwidth, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
             NotifyOnValidationError=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Here are the .Net Properties in my VM:

```
    public TMod Modulation
    {
        get { return modulation_; }
        set { modulation_ = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Modulation"); }
    }

    public Channel.TBnd IFBandwidth
    {
        get { return chan_.IFBandwidth; }
        set
        {
            chan_.IFBandwidth = value; 
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IFBandwidth"); 
        }
    }

    public Channel.TBnd[] BandwidthOptions
    {
        get
        {
            return (Channel.TBnd[])System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(Channel.TBnd));
        }
    }
```

Here are the enums:

```
    public enum TMod
    {
        FM = 0,
        AM = 1,
        P25 = 2,
        TRK = 3
    }

    public enum TBnd
    {
        Std = 0,
        Nar = 1,
        Wide = 2,
        XWide = 3
    }
```

Comment: If you don't understand bindings read **[this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)**.

Comment: Do you get binding errors in the output window of VisualStudio?

Comment: Is is at simple as additionally setting the SelecteValuePath or using the SelectedItem binding instead? Is the trigger needed? You should be able to just set IFBandwith in the viewmodel and it will set the selected value in the combobox.

Comment: @Jerod: Sounds more like an answer than a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your ComboBox binding to use SelectedValue instead of SelectedPath. That will properly set the IFBandwidth view model property when the value is changed.

What exactly is the trigger going to be used for? It may be a better option to change your Modulation property to be something like this...

```
public TMod Modulation
{
    get { return modulation_; }
    set
    {
        modulation_ = value; 
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Modulation");

        if( modulation == TMod.P25 )
        {
            IFBandwith = TBand.Wide;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I actually changed the VM like you suggested and that work.  Dumb question, but I don't see where SelectedPath is used in the ComboBox  XAML.  I think I must not be understanding binding syntax.

Comment: Sorry, I meant SelectedValuePath. Although, on second thought, I don't think that it would have solved your problem.

Comment: I guess I was hoping to do it all in XAML.  Do you understand why it doesn't work?  I was wondering if a converter was required because of a type incompatibility??  Interestingly I can disable the combobox with a setter that sets the IsEnabled property to false, so I know the trigger is working.

Comment: It could definitely be a conversion problem. A string to integer converter might be necessary. I don't know the full design requirement but it from what I see is that this is data driven logic which makes sense to be in the VM. I personally only use triggers to manipulate the look of the view (visibility, color, etc) not to change the model's data.